# why does this error occured in hyperledger Fabric 2.2 ,could not validate identity's OUs: certifiersIdentifier does not match?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

When I try to up the network,using docker-compose, peer exited with the below mentioned message.

*panic: Failed putting our own identity into the identity mapper: failed classifying identity: Unable to extract msp.Identity from peer Identity: could not validate identity's OUs: certifiersIdentifier does not match*

**Here is the complete log of a peer -**

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/identity.NewIdentityMapper({0x18218e0, 0xc00007d140}, {0xc00012d400, 0x3c7, 0x3c7}, 0xc002a2e410, {0x17f0020, 0xc000070fb0})
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/identity/identity.go:83 +0x24e
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip.New(0xc0002a2640, 0x113dba6, {0x17f0020, 0xc000070fb0}, {0x18218e0, 0xc00007d140}, {0xc00012d400, 0x3c7, 0x3c7}, 0xc002a2e120, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/gossip/gossip_impl.go:98 +0x4f0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/service.New({0x7f94b7e4e898, 0xc0003659e0}, 0xc002a2d290, {0xc000042152, 0x20}, 0x0, {0x18218e0, 0xc00007d140}, {0x17f0020, 0xc000070fb0}, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/gossip/service/gossip_service.go:258 +0x1d0
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.initGossipService({0x17f19e0, 0xc0004fdae0}, {0x1802940, 0x21044e0}, 0xc000091f90, {0x182c888, 0xc0003659e0}, 0x0, {0xc000042152, 0x20}, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/start.go:1208 +0x827
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.serve({0x11dd300, 0xc0001bdd30, 0xc0001bdd08})
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/start.go:453 +0x2450
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node.glob..func6(0x1fbcbc0, {0x21044e0, 0x0, 0x0})
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/internal/peer/node/start.go:127 +0x56
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x1fbcbc0, {0x21044e0, 0x0, 0x0})
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762 +0x60e
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x1fbd2e0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852 +0x2dc
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/peer/main.go:54 +0x347
```

Comment: Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue I was getting due to incorrect NodeOU configuration in config.yaml file.
Certificate had different OU and in config.yaml I was declaring the different one.